# Problem with giving names to Instantiate objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to create similar objects by `Instantiate()`. Also I need to call them something like mob1, mob2, mob3, etc. How can I do it by code? (I have problem with naming them, not with creating them).

Thanks.

Comment: why not create a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Its Simple:

```
    GameObject go = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    go.transform.name = "mob" + index;
    index++;
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't really know about `transform.name`... But thanks for the help)

Comment: as stated below it can work with go.transform.name or go.name its the same

Comment: It's actually [`Object.name`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html), and you can do `go.name = ...` as well, both update the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public GameObject CloneObject(GameObject objectToInstanitate, int i)
{
    GameObject mob = Instantiate(objectToInstanitate);
    mob.name = "mob" + i.ToString();
    return mob;
}
```